# my put method duplicate the code insteade of updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

i am trying to store user data in mongodb using put method .my intension is to update those data if there exist or create new. but my method create new data insteade of updating..
this code is from client side(here first i uploaded my image to the imgbb then i save it to server).. .

const image = data.image[0];

```
     const formData = new FormData();
     
     formData.append('image',image)
    

    const API_KEY = '4957c3c668ded462db1fb1002c4535e6';
    const url = `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=${API_KEY}`;

    fetch(url,{
        method : 'POST',
        body : formData,
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.success){
            console.log('image',result.data.url)
            const img = result.data.url;
            const dataOfuser = {
                user : user?.displayName,
                email : user?.email,
                phone: data.phone,
                city: data.city,
                education: data.education,
                img: img
            }
            console.log(dataOfuser)

            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/user/:${user.email}`,{
                    method:"PUT",
                    headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 },
                body : JSON.stringify(dataOfuser)
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if(data.acknowledged){
                    toast.success('Profile Updated')
                }
            })
        }
    })
};
```

these are the code from mongodb

app.put('/user/:email',async(req,res)=>{

```
        const email = req.params.email;
        
        const user = req.body;
        
        const filter = { email: email };
        
        const options = { upsert: true };
        
        const updateDoc = {
        
          $set: user,
        
        };
        
        const result = await userCollection . updateOne ( filter , updateDoc , options);
        
        res.send(result);
      
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send email and user as body and

```
app.put("/user/email", async (req, res) => {
const { dataOfuser } = req.body; //this finds all
const { email, user, phone, city, etc} = dataOfuser; //this extracts the values, but probably better to send each values by themselves
```

You can also just send user and email etc on their own, instead of as one object:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ user, email, phone, city, education, img })
```

You can also try to add curlybraces around dataOfuser in the body: JSON.stringify({ dataOfuser })

```
const res = await userCollection
    .updateOne(
        { email: email} *find the user by his email*
        { $set: {email: email, phone: phone, city: city etc.}}) *set email to email from body*
})
```

You should also have default value in inputs as their current value, so the fields doesn't get overwritten as null or blank

Comment: thanks for replying .i am still facing the same problem..if i am not wrong then the {user:user} is the document to update and the { $set: {email: email} is for query ..is it?

Comment: Are you just trying to update the email still, or more values? Added descriptions btw

Comment: trying to find the data from mongo  using email, then update the hole user info..hope you understand me..if not please ask me again

Comment: something like that?